# Error on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`
Error   2   `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` does not contain a definition for `CommandText` and no extension method `CommandText` accepting a first argument of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)Ok, guys i going try be specifc, srry me. I go send my program if you can help me. I am begginer please sorry some errors.

```
    const string _strconn = @"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AGENDA_TEL;PersistSecutity Info=True;User ID=su;Password=admin123";
    string nome, celular, telefone, descricao, Vsql;
    int cod=0;

    SqlConnection dbConn = null;
    SqlConnection dbCmd = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <sumary>
    /// Aqui vai ficar toda a parte de manipulação de dados que vem e vai para o banco
    /// dbInsert() -> Faz o cadastro de dados no banco
    /// dbUpdate() -> Faz alteração de dados já existentes no banco
    /// dbDelete() - Faz a exclusão de contatos através do ID_Contato
    /// </sumary>


    public void dbInsert()
    {
        dbConn = new SqlConnection(_strconn);
        dbCmd = new SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            nome = tb_nome.Text;
            descricao = tb_desc.Text;
            celular = mtb_celular.Text;
            telefone = mtb_telefone.Text;

            Vsql = " Insert Into  Agenda (nome, telefone, celular,descrição) VALUES('" + nome + "','" + telefone + "','" + celular + "','" + descricao + "')";


            dbCmd.CommandText = Vsql;

            dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

            dbConn.Open();

            dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dbConn.Close();

        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e + " Error ao cadastrar", " Erro ");
        }

           private void bt_save1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbInsert();
    }

    public SqlConnection objConn { get; set; }
}
```

}

}

Comment: And what is the answer which you expect us to provide?;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you provide more information?  All we have so far is a pair of exception messages.  Can you post the part of your .Net code that generates the exceptions?

Comment: Its pretty obvious that you trying to pass wrong data to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is caused by trying to store an object of type SqlCommand into a variable of type SqlConnection. Try changing the type of the variable you are storing your SqlCommand in, to SqlCommand.

The second error is caused by changing a property that is not part of a SqlConnection, however it is part of SqlCommand. Make sure you are setting that property of a SqlCommand object.

By the way, if you want more help, it would be useful to post the code that causes the errors so people can suggest more concrete solutions.